# "Restore to previous versions"?

Tags: windows, backup, small-business-server

I just discovered "restore to previous versions" when right clicking a file on Small Business Server.

What mechanism is this feature using?  Is this an automatic backup mechanism that is part of the operating system?

Comment: What OS is this? Windows Server 2008?

Comment: SBS. 2008 from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered the [Windows Volume Copy Shadow Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968832(VS.85).aspx). This does do some backup, but I'm not exactly sure to what extent. I would read up on the service before relying on it to restore files.